# Angular ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts

Tags: angular, rxjs

Angular ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts

Node Version : 8.9.4
Angular version : 6.0.8

When running the angular application I am getting below library issue.

```
ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,74): error TS1005: ';' expected.
    node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,77): error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

Here are my versions
    Node Version : 8.9.4
    Angular version : 6.0.8

Do we have any option to fix this library issue related to rxjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue resolved.

I investigated that rxjs released a new version: 6.4.0. And it broke the build. According to review, the minimum supported version of TypeScript is 2.8. If you don't want to update TypeScript version, just change "rxjs": "^6.0.0", to "rxjs": "6.3.3" in package.json

```
npm install rxjs@6.3.3 --save
```